# What are my options for encrypting a mac server, but having it be able to reboot automatically after a power failure?

Tags: power, encryption, filevault

I have an old 2012 iMac running [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) that I'm using as a home server, and I have it set to reboot after a power failure, so that it boots back up and starts serving again as soon as power is restored without requiring me to do anything.

However, it's not encrypted, and I'd rather have the data on there be encrypted just in case the Mac or its drives get physically stolen or something, since I don't want to worry about any of its data getting out into the wild. But if I turn on [FileVault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault), the Mac won't be able to boot up automatically after a power failure.

Is there a way for me to protect the data on this server, but still have it be able to reboot automatically without an intervention from me?

The one constraint I have is that the main user account's home folder *does* contain some of the data I want to encrypt, so I can't really have all of the server's data running on a separate encrypted partition. Some of it is going to live on the system partition.

Comment: You need to establish what is technically called a 'root of trust'. What is the thing which if someone has access to they can access the data. Since you worried about the mac being stolen, it can't be the server hardware it self, and since you are not there to unlock it, it can't be you. What else do you have available during the unlock?

Comment: @user1937198 If I understand correctly, it would (preferably) be physical access to the system and the password. But I'm willing to compromise that a bit in order to have the convenience of the system being able to start up after a power failure, while still maintaining some protection. For example, the system's keychain could have the passwords for my non-system drives so that they mount automatically, which means that the drives on their own are encrypted, but combined with the system someone could gain access to them. (I'm not saying I want to do that, though -- just an example.)

Comment: What about a SSD drive set in concrete under the floor connected over USB..........  Then at a practical level the key can only be access by someone in your home.

Comment: If you were using ubuntu you could use mandos, and you would need another machine that contains the mandos server
https://www.recompile.se/mandos

It's more of a use case of having a lot of encrypted servers and just one server containing all of the keys to be able to boot all the other servers

But if you want to have fun, run it on a raspberry pi with a small battery backup and lock it somewhere. Because it's on the local network, if the mac exits the network and is then rebooted it wouldn't be able to decrypt the drive

It's the IT manager version of @Ian's solution

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any way for me to protect the data on this server, but still have it be able to reboot automatically without any intervention from me

#### Buy an Uninterrupted Power Supply

There is no better way to protect a server and its contents than a device that can withstand momentary power outages/fluctuations and gracefully shutdown in the event it is prolonged.

This will mitigate the need to manually enter a password for FileVault.  As most power disruptions are quite brief in duration a shutdown isn’t necessary.  For example, in severe thunderstorm, hurricane zone of South Florida where I’m located, I’ve only had the UPS initiate a shutdown once about a year ago; it’s a rare occurrence.

A UPS won’t just achieve what you’re looking to do: solve the reboot/FileVault password issue.  It will also protect both your hardware *and* data from the damage power failures can cause.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152333/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-what-are-my-options-for-encrypting-a-mac-server-bu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of the encryption is that the system itself does not contain the secret information needed to access whatever is encrypted.

Should you make boot unattended with the encrypted stuff accessible, the potential attacker can just replay the relevant parts of the startup sequence using the key material stored in the system.

Comment: This is all true, but I'm hoping there's something I can do to add in at least some protections rather than leaving everything unencrypted. For example, I've considered having the system drive be decrypted (so that automatic booting works) and my data drives remain encrypted. Of course in that case the system keychain will contain the passwords for the encrypted drives, but independently none of the devices will have any decrypted sensitive data. As I mentioned, though, the system drive contains some data I want to protect too, so I haven't gone forward with that idea.

Answer (score 5):

You have to choose to enable automatic log in and forego the FileVault pre boot screen where the OS isn’t running and the APFS storage is not yet unlocked or provide the hardware with a UPS that can avoid most unplanned reboots.

A KVM with internet remote access is the practical solution to authenticating after an unplanned restart. For planned restarts you can call `fdesetup authrestart` to stage one use pre-authorization keys so the machine can restart the OS and log in without human intervention.

Comment: I'm considering a KVM with remote access, but I figure that I won't always have the ability to use it when power is restored, and it'd be a lot better if starting up could somehow be automatic in a way that sacrifices a little security for some added convenience, but not too much.

Comment: They work great after power outages and with dozens and dozens of Mac’s on KVM and hundreds remote - it’s always FileVault that needs a human - not the UPS or KVM